# Insert into table from Drupal 7

Tags: database, users

I am very new to Drupal.

- I have a table called **`test`** with two fields: (int) id and (varchar) text
- When a new user signs up I want to store data on the table **`test`**

I'd like to know how can I do that. I really don't know how to start researching about this.

I think the most approximately that I have found is [Overriding user login](http://drupal.org/node/350634). I presume that it does what I want but in the pre-process functions I have to insert into the database. Question here how do I insert into the database from Drupal?

Could anyone clear my thoughts or point me to any good reference.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to actually override the login process to do this; The user module provides a hook ([`hook_user_insert()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.api.php/function/hook_user_insert/7)) which gets invoked any time a new user is created.

As far as inserting into the database goes, the best place to look first is the [Database abstraction layer documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/group/database/7) which goes into detail about the various database methods available.

In this specific case it's the [`db_insert()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_insert/7) function you're looking for. Your code might look something like this:

```
function MYMODULE_user_insert(&$edit, $account, $category) {
  db_insert('custom_table_name')
    ->fields(array(
      'id' => $account->uid,
      'text' => 'some text'
    ))
    ->execute();
}
```

This code would go inside a custom module; if you're not familiar with creating one of those check out the [Module developer's guide](http://drupal.org/developing/modules) which will tell you everything you need to know.

Comment: Many thanks man, but actually I need to do it in the registration. Is there any hook for the registration? and in which file should I put this code?

Comment: My bad I didn't read the question properly ;) I'll update the answer

Comment: There, that should make more sense